# How to pass Data from one view controller to another view controller without using seague and storyboard

Tags: swift

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NewI.png]

[image]

Please Do it Without Using Storyboard.

when I click on radio button in the popup.When I click on 'Ok' The title of the radio button will be the  button title in main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get title from `UIButton.isSelected` property. You can set title in `viewDidLoad` method like

```
YourButton.setTitle("Title", for : .normal)
YourButton.setTitle("Selected Title", for : .selected)
```